# How to use async in ES6 constructors to call internal methods?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I am using `async` in a constructor to sequentially call internal methods. But, due to problems with localizing `this`, I have to wrap these functions in an anonymous function. I have to adopt a similar approach if I want to pass in extra arguments, too. For example:

```
class AsyncFriendly {

  constructor() {
    async.waterfall( [
        ( ...args ) => { this.methodA( ...args ); },
        ( ...args ) => { this.methodB( ...args ); },
      ],
      ( ...args ) => { this.allDone( "pass in", ...args ); }
    )
  }

  methodA( callback ) {
    callback( null );
  }

  methodB( callback ) {
    callback( null );
  }

  allDone( letMeIn ) {
    console.log( 'done ' + letMeIn );
  }

}
```

This seems like an unwieldy sort of anti-pattern, and I'd like to find the proper pattern here.

Comment: Have you tried using [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)? `async.waterfall([this.methodA.bind(this), ...])`

Comment: Is this really an ES6 problem? Wouldn't you have the same issue with the old-school constructor function plus prototype methods syntax that `class` is doing for you behind the scenes? (Except before ES6 you couldn't solve it with arrow functions, you'd use `.bind()` as already suggested.)

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts run a series of steps sequentially on object creation. Particularly, I am using this as a Lambda function on AWS. Step 1: lookup user. Step 2: check rate limit. Step 3: invoke PhantomJS. Step 4: crawl. Step 5: database result.